# Is there a way to get all the users within a Workspace and the corresponding groups they are part of

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get a list of the users within our workspace and all the groups that they are part of. I thought that this would be an easy ask but I am getting the following error
Error GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.members.list failed with error: Resource Not Found: groupKey

```
    function listAllUsersAndGroups() {
     var users = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
     domain: 'example.com',
     orderBy: 'email',
     maxResults: 100, // You can adjust this based on the number of users you want to retrieve
    });

   // Access the users and their groups
   var usersList = users.users;
   for (var i = 0; i < usersList.length; i++) {
     var user = usersList[i];
     Logger.log('User Email: ' + user.primaryEmail);
     Logger.log('User Name: ' + user.name.fullName);
     var groups = AdminDirectory.Members.list(user.primaryEmail, {
       maxResults: 100, 
     });
     // Check if the user is a member of any groups
     if (groups.members && groups.members.length > 0) {
       Logger.log('Groups:');
       for (var j = 0; j < groups.members.length; j++) {
         Logger.log(groups.members[j].email);
       }
     } else {
       Logger.log('User is not a member of any groups.');
     }
      Logger.log('------------------------');
     }
    }
    listAllUsersAndGroups();
```